# $\ln n+\sqrt{\frac12}+\sqrt{\frac23}+\ldots +\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}<\sqrt2+\sqrt{\frac32}+\sqrt{\frac43}+\ldots +\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Prove for every $n>1$

$$\ln n+\sqrt{\frac12}+\sqrt{\frac23}+\ldots
+\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}<\sqrt2+\sqrt{\frac32}+\sqrt{\frac43}+\ldots
+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}$$

Comment: So you mean $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

To use an induction you need to prove that:
$$\ln \left(\frac{n+1}{n} \right) +\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}} \leq \sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}} $$

So it sufficient to prove that for $x>1$:
$$\ln \left(x \right) +\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}} - \sqrt{x} <0$$
which is equivalent ($\xi=x^2$) to prove that for $\xi>1$:
$$f(\xi)=2\ln \left(\xi \right) +\frac{1}{\xi} - \xi <0 $$

Notice that:
$$f(1)=0$$
and for $\xi>1$:
$$f'(\xi)=\frac{2}{\xi}-\frac{1}{\xi^2}-1=-\frac{\xi^2-2\xi-1}{\xi^2}=-\frac{(\xi-1)^2}{\xi^2}<0$$